# android - Две поочередно анимирующих картинки, в целом создавающая фоновую анимацию

Tags: android, android-animation

Нужно сделать так, чтобы две картинки поочередно двигаясь снизу вверх создавали динамичную и плавную анимацию. одна уезжает вверх, вторая в этот момент появляется снизу. когда первая полностью уедет вверх, вторая должна повторить то, что сделала первая. потом вторая уезжает вверх и первая начинает выезжать снизу. вторая уходит вверх, первая доезжает до конца, уходит вверх, вторая появляется снизу. и так по кругу.

Comment: первая уезжает наверх, вторая начинает появляться снизу. выходит что первая двигаясь вверх освобождает экран и появляется белая фигня. нужно чтобы освободившееся место от сдвига первой картинки использовалось второй. анимация должна быть вот такой. не могу подробнее обьяснить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создайте две картинки высотой в экран.
2. Второй задайте координату Y равной высоте экрана.
3. В анимации одновременно двигайте обе картинки вверх.
4. В конце цикла анимации вехнюю картинку поместите вниз экрана также как в п.2 со второй картинкой.
5. Повторяйте пункты 3 и 4.